# Compatibility between contemporary Semigroupoid and Category.Constrained instances

Tags: haskell, category-abstractions

Once the Set (a, b) relationship was defined, I defined the Semigroupoid and Category instances based on the same composition function.

Surprisingly to me, it was not so possible to do so for the relation [(a, b)].

Why?

The search for Control.Category.Constrained with Hoogle does not give a positive result. The direct link to the library is:
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.3.1.1

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, TypeFamilies, ConstraintKinds #-}

module Question2 where

import Data.Semigroupoid
import Control.Category.Constrained
import Data.List as L
import Data.Map as M
import Data.Set as S

-- ============================== Set (a,b) ==============================

data RelationSP a b where
  IdRSP  :: RelationSP a a
  RSP :: (Ord a, Ord b) => Set (a,b) -> RelationSP a b

compRSP ::  RelationSP b c-> RelationSP a b -> RelationSP a c 
RSP r1 `compRSP` RSP r2 = RSP $
    S.foldr (\(x,y) acc -> S.union acc (S.map (\(_,b) -> (x,b))  $ S.filter (\(w,z) -> y == w) r1)
            ) S.empty r2 

instance Semigroupoid RelationSP where
    o = compRSP

instance Category RelationSP where
  type Object RelationSP o = Ord o
  id = IdRSP
  (.) = compRSP

-- ============================== [(a,b)] ==============================

data RelationLP a b where
  IdLP  :: RelationLP a a
  RLP ::  (Eq a, Eq b) => [(a,b)] -> RelationLP a b
  -- RLP :: [(a,b)] -> RelationLP a b -- Possible, if you do not define the Semigroupoid instance.

compRLP :: (Eq a1, Eq b, Eq a2) =>
     RelationLP a2 b -> RelationLP a1 a2 -> RelationLP a1 b     
RLP r2 `compRLP` RLP r1 = RLP $ L.nub [(a, b) | (t, b) <- r2, (a, t') <- r1, t == t']

instance Semigroupoid RelationLP where
    o = compRLP  
{-    ERROR:
      No instance for (Eq i) arising from a use of ‘compRLP’
      Possible fix:
        add (Eq i) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            o :: forall j k1 i.
                 RelationLP j k1 -> RelationLP i j -> RelationLP i k1 -}

instance Category RelationLP where
  type Object RelationLP o = Eq o
  id = IdLP
  (.) = compRLP
```

Comment: Ah yes. I thought about whether to include `Semigroupoid` in `constrained-categories` when I wrote it, but if at all I would have made it a superclass of `Category`, and I decided to keep it simple there (“YAGNI”, and I wanted my hierarchies to resemble the unconstrained `base` one as much as possible). Maybe I should change that; anyways I also have split up `Arrow` into `Cartesian`, `Morphism` and `PreArrow`.

Comment: What do you want to use the `Semigroupoid` instance for? Might be useful for me to know, to decide how to move the design of the package forward.

Comment: @leftaroundabout is a question that emerged from the attempts I am making to define various types of Relation using X.Constrained classes. For now I am still waiting for an affirmative answer to my previous post on Control.Functor.Constrained (an answer that includes the check that I entered later). I think that for some if not all types of Relation can be defined as Foldable.Constrained instances. But it all seems very precarious and above all difficult to understand.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Furthermore, I think that Relation is in a more natural way an instance of Semigroupoid than of Category, as it appears that identity is defined in an "artificial" way and has no real utility and / or use.

Comment: That's true, `id` is actually surprisingly nontrivial in several important categories!